# modify settings.settings from different app

Tags: c#, wpf, settings.settings

I have a console application and am currently storing some settings data in the .settings file.  I would like to add a front-end, preferably using wpf, that allows administrators to modify the settings data.

Is it a good idea to utilize the .settings file, or should I create a custom xml file and just use the standard xml assemblies to update/modify the data?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be harder to modify settings files from another application, you should just use a custom XML file unless you really need to track the scope of the settings (user/application). If you do maybe this will help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx

Comment: I don't really have a need to track the scope, so I may just use a custom xml file.  Thanks.